# How to install Seaborn wrapper in Julia?

Tags: julia, seaborn

I want to use seaborn python library in Julia. I have seen that a wrapper already exists (https://github.com/JuliaPy/Seaborn.jl). However when I try

`Pkg.add("Seaborn.jl")`

I get error:

```
ERROR: The following package names could not be resolved:
 * seaborn (not found in project or manifest)
Please specify by known `name=uuid`.
```

Is there a simple way to install the wrapper?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Seaborn.jl` seems not to be Julia 1.0 ready. However, you can use `PyCall` with `PyPlot` and be happy :-)

The instruction below are for Julia 1.0. Firstly, make sure that you have all packages - press `]` to go to the package manager:

```
(v1.0) pkg> add Conda
(v1.0) pkg> add PyCall
(v1.0) pkg> add PyPlot
```

Now let us install `seaborn` for Julia

```
using Conda    
Conda.add("seaborn")
```

Once installed let us make a plot:

```
using PyPlot   # important!
using PyCall
@pyimport seaborn as sns
x=randn(1000);
sns.distplot(x);
```

This worked for me.